# Awesome window manager has horizontal tearing?

Tags: video, awesome-wm, tearing

so i am having an issue with awesome (running Debian but doesn't matter because it does this on all my hardware). video gets ripples along the middle(vlc and mplayer and totem), scrolling no matter what app. never really cared much until i switched to awesome on my desktop, the problem is 100X more annoying on multiple large displays.
running nvidia btw, does the same on my intel 4000 graphics laptop
thanks!

UPDATE: compton at the end of my ~/.xinitrc solves this issue for anyone stumbling upon this. also sorry for question in wrong site

Comment: Off-topic, belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: compton at the end of my ~/.xinitrc solves this issue for anyone stumbling upon this. also sorry for question in wrong site